# For-loop and object naming

Tags: c++

I'm making a for loop that will get 20 inputs from a user and then I'm gonna store the input in a `vector`. I want to name the object 20 different times in the `for loop`.

Right now I have this:

```
vector<product*> productdetails;

for (int x = 1; x < 21; x++)
{
    Product*p1 = new product(0, "egrg", "rgdrg");
    cout << "Enter manufacturer for item #"<< x <<": ";
    p1->setmanufacturer();
    cout << "Enter name for item #" << x << ": ";
    p1->setname();
    cout << "Enter id for item #" << x << ": ";
    p1->setID();
    cout << endl;
    productdetails.push_back(p1);
}
```

How do I change the `p1` to `p(x)` so that every time the loop ends/start, I'll have a new product name? Like at the start, `x` will be `1` and my first product will be `p1`. When the loop ends and x++, x will become 2 and I'll have p2.

Comment: `p1` is a local variable. Why do you care what it's called?

Comment: There is no need to.  Every iteration `p1` will become a new `Product*` and it get copied into the vector

Comment: If you want to get the last element of the vector, use `productdetails.back()`.

Comment: @J.Will Read about [Scope (Visual C++)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b7kfh662.aspx) may help.

Comment: You probably want to pass `x` to `setID`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is mostly fine as it is. There's no reason to worry about naming variables `p1`, `p2`, `p3`, etc. Presumably you're attempting this because you want to, for example, access product 4 later in your code via the variable `p4`. However, if your products are added to the vector in a guaranteed order you will always be able to access product 4 by accessing the 4th index in the `productdetails` vector.

```
const size_t MAX_PRODUCTS = 20;

vector<product*> productdetails(MAX_PRODUCTS);

// product ids start from zero since vector indexes start at zero
for (size_t iii = 0; iii < MAX_PRODUCTS; ++iii)
{
    productdetails[iii] = new product(iii, "egrg", "rgdrg");
    cout << "Enter manufacturer for item #"<< iii <<": ";
    productdetails[iii]->setmanufacturer();
    cout << "Enter name for item #" << iii << ": ";
    productdetails[iii]->setname();
    // id is always the same as iii
    cout << endl;
}

// do something with product number 4
productdetails[4]->do_something();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems fine. When you do a `push_back` a copy of the current `p1` value is made and placed in the vector. So it is perfectly safe to assign a new value to `p1` in the next loop-iteration.

However, if you for some (strange) reason want to do use `x` in the main loop, you could pre-allocate 20 elements in the vector and then use `x` in the loop to index the elements.

```
vector<product*> productdetails(20, nullptr);

for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++)
{
        productdetails[x] = new product(0, "egrg", "rgdrg");

        cout << "Enter manufacturer for item #"<< x <<": ";
        productdetails[x]->setmanufacturer();
        cout << "Enter name for item #" << x << ": ";
        productdetails[x]->setname();
        cout << "Enter id for item #" << x << ": ";
        productdetails[x]->setID();
        cout << endl;
}
```

Another consideration is:

Do you really need pointers to product?

Why not store the product in the vector like this:

```
vector<product> productdetails;

for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++)
{
        productdetails.emplace_back(0, "egrg", "rgdrg");  // Constructs a new product
                                                          // at the back of vector


        cout << "Enter manufacturer for item #"<< x <<": ";
        productdetails[x].setmanufacturer();
        cout << "Enter name for item #" << x << ": ";
        productdetails[x].setname();
        cout << "Enter id for item #" << x << ": ";
        productdetails[x].setID();
        cout << endl;
}
```

Then you don't need to take care of `delete`-ing the memory later on.

Answer (score -3):

i don't think you can add a variable name at runtime with C/C++, and i don't quite understand what are you trying to do, does the below code help?

```
vector<product*> productdetails(21+1);

for (int x = 1; x < 21; x++)
{
        productdetails[x] = new product(0, "egrg", "rgdrg");
        Product*p1 = productdetails[x];
        cout << "Enter manufacturer for item #"<< x <<": ";
        p1->setmanufacturer();
        cout << "Enter name for item #" << x << ": ";
        p1->setname();
        cout << "Enter id for item #" << x << ": ";
        p1->setID();
        cout << endl;
        productdetails.push_back(p1);
}
```

Comment: Do you really want a push_back in the loop?

Comment: You already place the product into the vector on the first line of the loop. The push_back at the end places it into the vector a second time.